# How to get multiple selected items in listbox wpf?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, listbox

I am confused on how to retrieve multi selected values from listbox in wpf.

In XAML I have the following listbox with selection mode multiple.

```
 <ListBox Height="100" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="139,207,0,0" Name="listBox1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120" SelectionChanged="listBox1_SelectionChanged" SelectionMode="Multiple" />    

 <Button Content="Button" Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="319,220,0,0" Name="button1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75" Click="button1_Click" />
```

How do I check in foreach loop now?

```
        foreach (ListItem li in listBox1.Items)
        {
                ?? // how to check li is selected or not
        }
```

Comment: Read the [doc](http://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.listitem%28v=vs.100%29.aspx), `li.Selected`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You will find them in [ListBox.SelectedItems](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.listbox.selecteditems.aspx).

```
foreach (var item in listBox1.SelectedItems)
{

}
```

Comment: Oh thnx..it was SelectedItems not items.

Comment: thanks for your answer - is there any way to obtain the classes which each SelectedItem contains?

Comment: Sorry, I'm not sure what you mean. SelectedItems is a selection of items from your Items or ItemsSource collection and of same type. If you have multiple classes in there you could use typeof or nameof operator to distinguish between them or show their name.

Comment: thx for your response - what i mean: each selected item represents an instance of a Person class (which i've defined in my code). I want to get to that same person instance given a particular selectedItem instance - is there a way to do this?

Comment: Each SelectedItem is a reference to the corresponding Item instance. Does this answer your question?
Maybe it's better to ask this as a new question because it's not related to this question and I'm still unsure what the problem is. Sorry.

Answer (score 0):

another example

```
int j = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < lbItems.Items.Count; i++)
{
   if (lbItems.Items[i] == lbItems.SelectedItems[0])
   j++;
}
MessageBox.Show(lbItems.Items.IndexOf(lbItems.SelectedItems[0]).ToString()
+ string.Format("\r\nThere are {0} occurences of this object in this list",j) )
```